# Safe Versions of STL on Linux

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, clang

[The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference, 2nd Edition](http://www.cppstdlib.com/) refers to *safe versions of the STL* which support various utilities such as runtime bounds checking for `operator []` and other operators. For example, on p247:

> Thus, it is a good idea to use a "safe" STL, at least during software
>    development. A first version of a safe STL was introduced by Cary Horstmann (see [[SafeSTL]](http://www.horstmann.com/safestl.html)). Another example is the "STLport", which is
>   available for free for almost any platform at [[STLPort]](http://www.stlport.org/). In addition,
>   library vendors now provide flags to enable a "safer" mode, which
>   especially should be enabled during development.

Both suggested packages seem relatively dated (last developed in 2008) and don't include more recent C++11/14 features. Are there any more recent reputable implementations available for/with some of the major compilers on Linux (`gcc` or `clang`) or as standalone libraries?

Comment: Can you actually quote where it says this?  I think it might be advicating the use of `at` instead of `operator[]` as `at` does bounds checking where `operator[]` does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

libstdc++ has a [debug mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html), which can be enabled by defining `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` when compiling.

> The libstdc++ debug mode performs checking for many areas of the C++ standard, but the focus is on checking interactions among standard iterators, containers, and algorithms, including:
>
> - *Safe iterators*: Iterators keep track of the container whose elements they reference, so errors such as incrementing a past-the-end iterator or dereferencing an iterator that points to a container that has been destructed are diagnosed immediately.
> - *Algorithm preconditions*: Algorithms attempt to validate their input parameters to detect errors as early as possible. For instance, the `set_intersection` algorithm requires that its iterator parameters `first1` and `last1` form a valid iterator range, and that the sequence `[first1, last1)` is sorted according to the same predicate that was passed to set_intersection; the libstdc++ debug mode will detect an error if the sequence is not sorted or was sorted by a different predicate.

Bounds checking in `operator[]` [is included](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49eaa58639587c07).

Comment: I have read about `enabled by defining _GLIBCXX_DEBUG` at a few places, but what **precisely** does that mean? Do I pass `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to the compiler via command line?

Comment: @shuhalo yup! -